# Command not found when run in sudo but gives output when run as normal user

Tags: linux, pandoc

When I run the below command using sudo it gives me command not found but when I run it using normal user it gives me the version output

```
[root@localhost ~]# pandoc -v
bash: pandoc: command not found

[vagrant@localhost ~]]$ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.17.2
```

Seems like Apparently pandoc was installed using the user vagrant ,is there a way or command  where I can also enable pandoc to run on root user ,so that I can run my code on root user also .

Comment: `which pandoc` will give you the current path in the current environment of the executable pandoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` user usually has a more pared-down `PATH` for security reasons.  Specify the full path to the `pandoc` binary and things should work fine.  As the `vagrant` user, run `type pandoc` which should tell you the actual path to the binary.

Comment: should I specify full path of the binary in $PATH variable ?

Comment: Yes, for the root user.

Comment: I would discommend changing `root`'s path; simply specify the path to the binary when using the program _as_ root, e. g. `/path/to/pandoc`.